# Simulation of global and local variables in Coq

Tags: scope, global-variables, coq, local-variables, coqide

I'm trying to simulate global and local variables in Coq, but I don't even know how to start. Is there anybody that can give me a hint or some pieces of advice? I read a lot of documentation about this programming language, but I can't figure it out. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you want to prove something about a program written in a language with global variables?  Or do you want to write a program in Coq's language? (If it is the latter, what program is it that you want to write, and why does it have to use global variables?)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by "local" and "global". Variables in Coq work differently from most programming languages, because they cannot be modified.  The closest thing to a global variable is a top-level definition, and the closest thing to a local variable would be a local definition:

```
Definition i_am_a_global : nat := 42.

Definition my_function (my_parameter : nat) : nat :=
  (* Function parameters are always local *)
  let my_local := my_parameter + my_parameter in
  my_local + i_am_a_global.
```

Comment: I see your point and I understand what you explained to me (really appreciated, btw). The fact is, I am trying to "re-write" some functionalities from C++ in Coq and this one was a challenging one to me because I learned how to use variables in Coq, but not to create some sort of new type (scope) that can be either global or local.

Comment: @geeky90846 Maybe you could include in your question a code snippet in C++ that you would like to translate to Coq.

Comment: Let's consider this program: 


// Global variable declaration:
int g;
int main () {
   // Local variable declaration:
   int a, b;

   // actual initialization
   a = 10;
   b = 20;
   g = a + b;

   cout << g;
   return 0;
}

Comment: @geeky90846 I am not sure which feature exactly you would like to translate. Usually in Coq you cannot produce output from a program. And there isn't a way of declaring a variable first and only defining it later...

Comment: Alright, I think I got it! Thanks for helping me out!